# How we can call a procedure which can accept array of objects as input parameter for oracle db

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js

Suggest  a oracle procedure which accepts Array of Objects as Input Parameter   With NodeJS , Sequelize ,Oracle .

**For Oracle Procedure I Followed below
**

```
create or replace TYPE ROLE_OBJECT as object(
"ROLE" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
"ROLECODE" VARCHAR2 (255 CHAR),
"ROLEID" NUMBER(1)
);

create or replace TYPE ROLE_ARRAY is table of ROLE_OBJECT;

create or replace PROCEDURE  ROLESUPDATING(useResultIn IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. useResultIn.count
  LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(useResultIn.count);
  END LOOP;
END;

BEGIN
ROLESUPDATING([{'role':'admin','rolecode':'adm','roleid':'1'}]);
END;
```

/*
It is not giving the length of the array

It is giving below Error

ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "Collect.ROLESUPDATING", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 7

*/

Comment: For those of us who don't know "sequelize ORM/Node JS", can you please provide a sample input and output you hope to get? I'm sure it can be done in PL/SQL, we just need to understand what you're after.

Comment: Input :[{'role':'admin','rolecode':'adm','roleid':'1'}]         ,  out put : I want to access the length and  the elements  of the array ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[{prop:value}]` are all javascript syntax, none of which makes any sense in PL/SQL. Instead, you can do this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  ROLESUPDATING(useResultIn IN ROLE_ARRAY)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. useResultIn.count
  LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(useResultIn.count);
  END LOOP;
END;

BEGIN
  ROLESUPDATING(ROLE_ARRAY(ROLE_OBJECT('admin','adm',1)));
END;
```

Note that in addition to restructuring your actual call to ROLESUPDATING, it was also necessary to charge your parameter type from `varchar2` to `role_array` (the collection type). In PL/SQL, you instantiate an object or collection by calling the type name like a function and passing in the property values like arguments. You can also nest the call to an object type and a collection type to create the collection in one statement, as in my answer.

Comment: Above PL/SQL Call working perfectly thanks for that .But I couldn't find any way to call the above procedure from sequelize  using NodeJs .

Comment: Perhaps you should post another, new question just on NodeJs tag asking how to call an Oracle procedure.